# Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager'

Tags: android

Mac OS X ver 10.6.8
Android Developer Tools   Build: v22.3.0-887826 (Includes Eclipse Platform)

NEED HELP IN A ERROR:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'test'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

How to fix it please any help.  I new to ADT

Comment: Please paste full stack trace (click on details... and paste the results).

Comment: i get the same error on Mac 10.8 in eclipse. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I recently came with such problem just after I installed SVN on my eclipse. It suffered me a lot to recalled that I had installed SVN. After I **uninstalled SVN** everything worked out just fine. Hope this will help!